# Issues with OleDB Conn String and VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

I'm getting an Data type mismatch in criteria expression error when I run the following statement, I've picked it apart and cant for the life of me see where it's going wrong ! Likely due to my beginner level of knowledge, but it's to the best of my ability!

Here's my code ;

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim UserName As String
    UserName = System.Environment.UserName
    Dim Month = Date.Now.ToString("MM")
    Dim CS As ConnectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnCIM")
    Dim Table As New DataTable
    Dim Adapt As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [LoginName], [DisplayName], [Date], [SessionID], [The wait time was acceptable] , [The length of the chat session was appropriate] , [Professionalism of the agent] , [Effectiveness of the response] , [Overall opinion of the chat service] , [Related Comments] , [Not Resolved Comments] FROM [Chat_Dump] WHERE (([LoginName] = @UserName) AND ([Date] = @Month))", CS.ToString())
    Adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", Textbox1.text)
    Adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Month", TextBox2.Text)

    TextBox2.Text = Month


    Adapt.Fill(Table)

    GridView1.DataSource = Table
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

The textbox's are there for testing only,textbox 1 gets replaced with UserName and I want textbox2 to be replaced by Month.

In short, I have a table of data that when each user views, I want it to pull their username from domain login and display their records for the current month.

Thanks! and sorry for my low level of knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

If `[Date]` is a `DATETIME` you need to extract the month from it, then compare to your month value.

```
... AND MONTH([Date]) = @Month
```

(The integer `DateTime.Now.Month` is a better choice that `ToString("MM")`)

Comment: I've just tried changing that as you have mentioned ;

Dim Month = DateTime.Now.Month

This returns the current month as 7, however it does not return any records from the table, is this because the format on the table is xx/07/2015 etc?

Comment: Is the column type DATE/DATETIME ?

Comment: Yup when I open the table in access and view design the Datatype is set to Date / Time

Comment: If you copy the SQL string from your code (inserting `7/username`) and run it in SSMS/Access or whatever your using does it work?

Comment: If I run the string, entering a known user for user name and month as 07, nothing is found and I get "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated" error. However if I enter a known user and the full date of a known record eg 15/07/2015, It finds that record fine.

Comment: Add `MONTH([Date])` to the `SELECT` list and query using a full date, is it returned as `7` ?